# Call function on child state angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In my view have a link that calls a function like: `<a href=/albums ng-click='findAll()'>`, and it all works fine,  but when u type directly to the URL  /albums nothing happens, findAll() function doesn't trigger.

My question is, Is there anything that I can do using states in Angular that when this state is executed to automatically call that function findAll() and render the view with the data.

Kinldy Regards,

Comment: are you using same controller for different routes ?

Comment: @underscore No, in parent state I call another controller,  in child another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can add your function to `$rootScope`. Inject `$rootScope` for your parent controller.

```
app.controller('parentCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope){

    $rootScope.findAll = function(){

    /* your code here */

    };

});

<div ng-controller='parentCtrl' ng-init='findAll()'></div> <!-- parent Div -->
```

or you can use run function

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {

        $rootScope.findAll = function(){

        /* your code here */

        };

$rootScope.findAll(); // Call when angular bootstrap 

});
```

For both in your child controllers you can use ng-init to call it automatically

```
<div ng-controller='childCtrl' ng-init='findAll()'></div> <!-- child Div -->
```